# How do I recompile my NodeJS app to update files? Why are images encoded? Why is the workflow so bad?

Tags: node.js

Beginner question. Got an app running on a server, it is a complex one.

Now in the client directory there is an index file called index.html (I thought node was using express/routed, what is it doing there)

```
module.exports = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  //devtool: '#cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.dev.env
    }),
    // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
  ]
})
```

1) Why are the image URLS encoded? And I can instead paste absolute URLS? This is not developer friendly, makes me want to abandon Node right away if they dont have proper views and need extra steps

```
<img class="color loader-box-image" data-v-553e61a2="" alt=. src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....." LONG STRING />
```

2) Ok so assume I am updating the index file in there, it does not update the live page. I have to assume the index file is either cached or Node itself is caching some version of it. Is the index.html just a static file? And if not, why?

What are best practices to get a simplified workflow?

Thank you

Edit: I understand node itself is acting like a webserver (JS based) and that routes have to be established. How do static files play into this?

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "dependency-list": "^0.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-sparkline": "^2.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react-stockcharts": "^0.6.1",
    "sitemap": "^1.13.0",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-authenticate": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-axios": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-event-calendar": "git+https://git@github.com/adi-darachi/vue-event-calendar.git",
    "vue-multiselect": "^2.0.8",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-search-select": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^2.3.3",
    "vue-socket.io": "^2.1.1-a",
    "vue-tweet-embed": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-virtual-scroll-list": "^1.2.4",
    "vuetrend": "^0.2.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },



> "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^4.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^1.4.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "cross-spawn": "^5.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
    "inject-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "^1.4.0",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.31",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.12",
    "npm": "^5.5.1",
    "offline-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "opengraph-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "opn": "^5.1.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "selenium-server": "^3.0.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "sinon": "^4.0.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.8.0",
    "sitemap-webpack-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: Can we see an example of the "encoded image urls?" Node is probably not doing this. As for live updates, do you mean while developing locally?

Comment: Please provide any information about your setup as you can.  Are you using webpack, express, Vue, react, Angular?  What does your project setup look like?  What do you mean the images are URL encoded?  We have no way to reproduce the issues you describe without more information.

Comment: Sure: <img class="color loader-box-image" data-v-553e61a2="" alt=. src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR>

Comment: @zero298 asks a good question. Are you using webpack or anything to build your app? What frameworks are you using?

Comment: Your question isn't answerable. Node is largely irrelevant here. It is just a way to execute JavaScript. We have no idea what that JavaScript is doing. All we know is that you have some code, which you say is "complex", and you get some output. So we have a (very) vague idea of what is happening, no idea of what is supposed to happen, and no code.

Comment: You are conflating node and webpack.  Node isn't encoding those images, one of the webpack plugins is and is doing so to save you a network request.

Comment: Any `devDependencies`? Webpack?

Comment: You said "I understand node itself is acting like a webserver" but is it? Node **can** do that (as can any other programming language) and it often is, but we don't know if that is happening here.

Comment: Ok thanks, but is it even correct to modify the index.html file?

Comment: @mashup — How should we know?

Comment: You've got all sorts of dependencies on `vue` there, and that is designed to run *in a browser* and Node might be used as part of a build tool and might be used to provide some APIs for the client side code to talk to.

Comment: Awesome! We're getting there. How about that `webpack.config.js`. It might be split between client and server.

Comment: Thanks Max, I added the config.js from webpack.dev.conf.js which points to index.html -> when I modify this file, the main page is not getting updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are conflating node and webpack. Node isn't encoding those images, one of the webpack plugins is and is doing so to save you a network request.

Additionally, you said in one of your comments:

> Thanks, good advice but I cant. I simply need to modify some CSS and
>   swap the logo - that should be simple enough but for that I need to
>   get a basic understanding of NodeJS in very little time. I dont get
>   why there is an index.html file in the first place when I learned that
>   Node uses dedicated directories for files previously

You are using [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin).  That generates the `index.html` file for you.  Don't modify the generated file, modify the configuration that *generates* the file.  Otherwise you're going to get a regression.  Read the documentation on that plugin and you should be able to figure out where the logo is being drawn from in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this some sort of pre-built starter project, and the developer made some decisions which you don't fully understand yet.

Since this strategy has frustrated you, I recommend trying a **different** strategy: build the simplest possible project that you possibly can, using as few libraries as possible, and build out from there.  Good luck!

Comment: It sounds like he inherited the project. He might not be able to try a different strategy.

Comment: Thanks, good advice but I cant. I simply need to modify some CSS and swap the logo - that should be simple enough but for that I need to get a basic understanding of NodeJS in very little time. I dont get why there is an index.html file in the first place when I learned that Node uses dedicated directories for files previously

Comment: @mashup — It isn't Node you need to understand. It is how the project you are editing works. Node appears to be a small part of it.

Comment: @mashup using express, node can serve static files like an `index.html`. https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: @MaxBaldwin Apparently the index file is getting injected. Not sure about implications